# Display POJO as json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am wondering how I can display a POJO as a json object in a REST endpoint. This is the current controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/Stats")
public Statistics statsPage() {
    stats = scheduler.getStats();
    return stats;
}
```

however it returns the error that it couldn't find the corresponding `.jsp` file in my WEB-INF folder. (Likely due to the fact that I don't have one). So how am I to either a.)Display the pojo as a json object in the jsp file, or the more preferred method b.)just return the pojo as a json object?

Comment: did you try adding @RestController annotation to your controller?

Comment: Please do not include "SOLVED" in a question title, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to the controller (*facepalm*)

```
@RequestMapping("/Stats")
@ResponseBody
    public Statistics statsPage() {
        stats = scheduler.getStats();
        return stats;
    }
```

Comment: Another solution is to use the `@RestController` annotation instead of `@Controller` then no need to use `@ResponseBody`. It's more better when you use Spring's controller to make real Restfull apis and not mixing MVC and ajax endpoints (`@ResponseBody` is more used for an ajax endpoint in a MVC controller).

Comment: And please do not forget to mark this problem as solved ;)